# iOS Push notification service extension bundle id

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, bundle-identifier

I am confused why there should be a separate bundle id for the notification service. But, since that the case should the push notification enabled in both the app id and the notification id?

Should the Add groups be enabled too?

After that, when to use notifications provisioning profile created for notification id and when to use the ones created for the app id?

Comment: separate bundle is required to handle Content and service for push notification if you are trying to show image or video in notification. When we create UNNotificationServiceExtension and UNNotificationContentExtension. Here you have to add those both bundle to identify.

Comment: I didn’t understand can you elaborate?